# Can I use "not only … but also" in this sentence?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Can I use "not only … but" in the following sentence?

> According to the host, it serves not only to protect the house from the danger of a robbery, but also to prohibit a bad spirit as well.

Is there any differences between British English and American English?

Comment: As I understand it, your question is too vague by saying "any condition". Could provide some specific examples, especially related to where you believe the usage may not be correct?

Comment: The idiom is standard in every English dialect. If you have a more specific question, that would be better. For example, do you want to know if you could use "not only … (but) also …" in a specific case?

Comment: You can use it in that sentence (the "but" is **not** optional, by the way), but the final two words, "as well", are redundant because they mean the same as "but also": ergo, delete them.

Comment: The [Not Only... But Also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Only..._But_Also) part is fine, but the *"to prohibit a bad spirit as well"* isn't at all natural English. I'd suggest maybe *"to guard against bad spirits"*. Drop the *"as well"* bit, because it's pointless/irritating repetition of the concept already expressed by *"but **also**"*. (@Bill! - Snap! :)

Comment: @BillFranke for the words 'also' and 'as well' I just realized that! thank you!

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is about one and half metres wall surrounded a native house.  That wall is believed to protect the house from a robbery and bad spirit.

Comment: @Des: I'm still not clear exactly what you mean by *a bad spirit*, but it's not very natural English to say something will *"protect the house from a robbery"* either.

Comment: @FumbleFingers hmmmmm it is linked with 'supernatural things', if you follow.

Comment: You've just switched to plural yourself, with 'supernatural things'. Like I said originally, *"to guard against bad spirits"*.

Answer (score 1):

I would rephrase it as follows:

> According to the host, it not only serves to prevent robberies, but also serves to prevent bad spirits from entering.

The sentence is similar to "She not only wrote the text but also selected the illustrations." Notice that *not only* is written between the subject and the verb.
As others said in comments, *as well* is not necessary, since the sentence is already using *also*; using both is probably like writing "She was not only intelligent but also very musical too."

As for using *prohibit*, the verb is used as "prohibit something," "prohibit somebody from doing something," "prohibit doing something, or "prohibit something/somebody from doing something." In your sentence, *prohibit* was used as "prohibit somebody" which is not how the verb is normally used.

Comment: @Bill "According to the host, it not only serves to prevent robberies, but also serves to prevent bad spirits from entering. That wall was also a defence  against the supernatural attack from the outside part." How does it flow?

Comment: @Des: It flows well enough. But **the second sentence is gratuitous: an unnecessary definition of "to prevent bad spirits from entering"**; & **the second "serves" is unnecessary** ("...it not only serves to prevent robberies, but also to prevent bad spirits from entering"). Perhaps you'll like it better as "...it serves not only to prevent robberies, but also to prevent bad spirits from entering" or "...it serves both to prevent robberies, and to {prevent / prohibit / keep / block} bad spirits from entering".

Answer (score 1):

I think what you wrote is pretty close, I would write:

> According to the host, it not only serves to protect the house from the danger of **robbery**, but also to prohibit **bad spirits from entering**.

*robbery* does not require an article.
*the robbery* would refer to a specific robbery, and *a robbery* would refer to one robbery without specifying which one. But in your sentence, it's an unknown future event, with an unknown count. So an article is not needed.

I think [prohibit](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/prohibit) is OK, sense 2 - to prevent; hinder. It could be prevent (keep them out) or hinder (make it more difficult). I think it could apply to spirits.

Comment: Why is 'the' not needed before 'robbery'?

Comment: _the robbery_ would refer to a specific robbery, and _a robbery_ would refer to one robbery without specifying which one. But in your sentence, it's an unknown future event, with an unknown count.

Comment: Okay thanks.  How about these following lines: "A guide not only worked in foreign language, but also had a professional dedication for being available any time."

Comment: @Des I think the "not only … but" usage is OK. A couple of other points... It should be "a foreign language" because it is a specific language, we just don't know which one. If you did, you would likely say something like "in Spanish".  And "A guide" may be OK, but it seems like you are talking about a specific person. In that case, it should be "The guide".

Comment: Thanks always for your help!  The more I learn the more I know nothing :)